# Angular 4 - unit test with reflectiveinjector

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm struggling to write a unit test for this piece of code:

```
export class mycomp{
    currentComponent: any;

    @ViewChild('modal', { read: ViewContainerRef }) modal: ViewContainerRef;

    @Input() set componentData(data: any) {
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        const inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {
            return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};
        });
        const resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.modal.parentInjector);
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);
        const component = factory.create(injector);
        this.modal.insert(component.hostView);

        if (this.currentComponent) {
            this.currentComponent.destroy();
        }
        this.currentComponent = component;
    }
    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

}
```

My unit test is:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        mycomp,
    ]);

    comp = injector.get(mycomp);
});

describe('DataTableComponent: Isolated', () => {
    const data = {component: modal, inputs: 'string'};
    beforeEach(() => {
        const factory = (comp as any).resolver.resolveComponentFactory(modal);
        comp.moda.createComponent(factory);
    });
    describe('componentData()', () => {
        it('should call ', () => {
            comp.componentData = data;
        });
    });
});
```

What I get if I try to create the component is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

When I do not, by removing beforeEach, I get: cannot read property 'parentInjector' of undefined

How do I test it?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Don't remember it was ages ago, but remember that it was a struggle...